# How to call another function (temperature) as main function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was typing a sample code. Where I defined temperature as the main function, but I was unable to run it. It closed automatically without any input prompt.

```
def temperature():
    number = input('Enter what you want\n')
    values = number.split(' ')
    temperature = values[0]
    unitin = values[1]
    unitout = values[-1]
    print(temperature, 'this', unitin, 'is', unitout, 'working')  # this is working is a test statemment i was unsure
    print('This is a test function', number)


def main():
    temperature()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is the part of the code that ran. But as soon as I tried to change just the name of the main function it stopped working. I am not sure, does it only take the name "main"?

```
def readinput():
input_string = input('Enter what you want\n')
values = input_string.split(' ')
temperature = values[0]
unitin = values[1]
unitout = values[-1]
print(temperature, 'this', unitin, 'is', unitout, 'working')
print('This is a test function', input_string)


def temperature_converter():
    readinput()


if __name__ == "__temperature_converter__":
    temperature_converter()
```

This is the code that did not work. thank you.

Comment: Did it not run with any specific error message/stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code on its own, the variable `__name__` is automatically set to `"__main__"` by the interpreter. That does not have anything to do with your functions name. Have a look at [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

This should work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    temperature_converter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the contents of the special variable `__name__` that contains string `'__main__'` in case when the module is run by itself (as opposed to imported by another module) with the function `main()` -- these are totally unrelated things, and when you change the name of the function `main()` to whatever else you like, leave the string `__main__` alone, as it is.

Or you may remove the line starting with `if __name__ ==` completely,  it should work without is as well.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the whole block and just openly calling the function (temperature), worked.